# About the relation of linear independence of a set of vector and of the coefficients of those vector given a base

Tags: linear-algebra

If $w= a^1 v^1+\cdots +a^n v^n$, I call $(a^n, \ldots, a^n)$ the coefficients of the vector $w$. 
If a call $f(v)$ the function that associates every $w$ with its coefficients, 
I know that a set of vectors $(v^1,\ldots,v^n)$ is linearly independent if and only if $f(v^1),\ldots, f(v^n)$ are.
I tried to demonstrate using the fact that
$$f(a^1 v^1+... +a^n v^n) =a^1 f(v^1) +\cdots +a^n f(v^n)$$

but I'm not really getting it.
If you think of am example (like polynomial functions)  it becomes obvious, but I need to demonstrated it.

Also, if I made errors writing this, I apologize. English is not my first language.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The definition of $f$ isn't clear to me.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve readability. Please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have a set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$. Every $w \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
w = \alpha_1v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_nv_n
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

and you wish to define functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n : \operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $f_i(w) = \alpha_i$.

You claim that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ if and only if $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ is linearly independent.

In fact, if $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is not linearly independent then the functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ aren't even well-defined. That is because vectors from $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ won't have a unique representation as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$:

Namely, since $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, there exist not-all-zero scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ such that
$$0\cdot x_1 + \cdots + 0\cdot x_n = 0 = \lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots\lambda_nv_n$$

so the representation of $0$ is not unique.

The converse holds: if $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ is also linearly independent.

First of all, now the functions $f_i$ are well-defined since the representation in $(1)$ is unique.

Now take scalars $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ such that $$0 = \alpha_1 f_1 + \cdots + \alpha_nf_n$$

In particular, for some $v_j$ we have $f_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$ since the representation of $v_j$ is simply $$v_j = 0\cdot v_1 + \cdots + 0 \cdot v_{j-1} + 1\cdot v_j + 0\cdot v_{j+1} + \cdots + 0 \cdot v_n$$

So:

$$0 = 0(v_j) = \alpha_1 f_1(v_j) + \cdots + \alpha_nf_n(v_j) = \alpha_j$$

This holds for any $j = 1, \ldots, n$ so $\alpha_1 = \ldots = \alpha_n = 0$. This shows that $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Why did you write 0 = 0(vj)? Is it important follow the steps of the demonstration?

Comment: @User3 $0 = \alpha_1 f_1 + \cdots + \alpha_nf_n$ is an equality of two functions, where the function $0$ just maps every vector to $0$. If the two functions are equal, then they are equal when evaluated at any vector in $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$. Now evaluate them at $v_j$. The function $0$ will map $v_j$ to the scalar $0$, and the function $ \alpha_1 f_1 + \cdots + \alpha_nf_n$ will map $v_j$ to $\alpha_j$, as discussed. Therefore, $\alpha_j = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you refer to $f$ as a linear transformation, note that it is not true to assume $S=(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent $\Rightarrow f(S)$ is linearly independent. Think of the transformation $f(v_i)=\overrightarrow0$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. So it is not an if and only if statement.

You might want to prove that if S if linearly dependent, then f(S) is linearly dependent. to prove this you can show a non trivial solution for the equation $b_1f(v_1)+...+b_nf(v_n)=0$ where there exists $1\le i\le n$ such that $b_i\neq0$.

Since we assume S is linearly dependent, there exists $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in F$ some scalars and $1\le j\le n$ so that $\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_jv_j+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$ when $\alpha_j\neq0$.

Apply $f$ to both sides, we get:

$f(\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_jv_j+...+\alpha_nv_n$) = $f(0)$.
Since $f$ is a linear transformation- we know $f(0)=0$ and $f(\beta X+\gamma Y)=\beta f(X)+\gamma f(Y)$ so we get:

$\alpha_1f(v_1)+...+\alpha_jf(v_j)+...+\alpha_nf(v_n)=0$ and we know $\alpha_j\neq0$ $\Rightarrow$  $f(S)$ is a linear dependent set.